# Recurrence relation related proof

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary string that do not contain 00 or 11 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define $T_i(n)$ as the number of ternary strings of length $n \geq 1$ ending in $i$, for $i \in \{0,1,2\}$, then we have
$$T_0(n)=T_1(n-1)+T_2(n-1),$$
$$T_1(n)=T_0(n-1)+T_2(n-1), \text{ and}$$
$$T_2(n)=T_0(n-1)+T_1(n-1)+T_2(n-1)$$
for $n \geq 2$ (we append a $0$, $1$ or $2$, where allowed, to all possible strings of length $n-1$), and boundary cases: $T_i(1)=1$ for $i \in \{0,1,2\}$ and $T_0(2)=T_1(2)=2$ and $T_2(2)=3$.

If we define
$$T(n)=T_0(n)+T_1(n)+T_2(n)$$
then substituting in the above gives
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= 2T_0(n-1)+2T_1(n-1)+3T_2(n-1) \\
 &= 2T(n-1)+T_2(n-1) \\
 &= 2T(n-1)+T(n-2).
\end{align*}

This agrees with [A078057](http://oeis.org/A078057) on the OEIS.

Comment: the initial conditions would be: $T(1) = 3$ and $T(2) = 7$? for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$, respectively.